# Adding a label for an equation array on TeXstudio

Tags: equations, align

I need to create a label for an equation group in TeXstudio such as :

```
\begin{align} \label(myequations)
     eq1    \label(myequ1)
     eq2    \label(myequ2)
     eq3    \label(myequ3)
\end{align}
```

But, I got error:

```
 Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'myequations' will be lost. \end{align}
```

What I expect is that sometimes, I need to refer to the whole equation array as a group. Sometimes, I need to refer to one of the equations.

e.g.

```
     x + y = 8     (1.1)
     5x + 2y = 10  (1.2)
```

Sometimes, I need to refer to the whole equation group as (1) , sometimes, I need to refer to Equation (1.1).
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps the error is in the first label of your example `\label{myequations} is not labeling anything. Remove that and you should compile it without troubles.

Comment: @Aradnix, I can remove it, and it works well , but, i need to add a label for the whole equation array. thanks

Comment: Can you explain what this label is supposed to do? In what case would you refer to it and what output would you expect for such a reference?

Comment: Well you can label each equation or group them and use only a label, but try to juxtapose both criteria is redundant. Keep it simple and clear.

Comment: @Aradnix, Sometimes, I need to refer to the whole eq. array as a group. Sometimes, I need to refer to one of the equations.

Comment: Uhm... once I had a similar problem, but I don't remember how I solved it, let me see the code...

Comment: Well I used the subequations environment just as suggested you @egreg But I did not remember until look at my code. It is in my opinion, the most simple and functional solution for cases like yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to refer to the equations as a group, you probably want to use the `subequations` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Some text with a reference to the following group~\eqref{eq:group}; now the equations
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:group}
\begin{align}
A &= B \label{eq:A}\\
C &= D \label{eq:B}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
and a referencea to the first equation~\eqref{eq:A}. 
Also the second~\eqref{eq:B}.

\end{document}
```

[image]